# how do i convert this event handler into a command?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void GridSplitter_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    vm.positionX = e.GetPosition((sender as GridSplitter).Parent as UIElement).X;
}
```

the Parent is a VirtualizingStackpanel.
I kind of understand the idea behind commanding, but am still having trouble understanding how to implement it. This event handler is taking the X coordinate of the Mouse and sending it to the ViewModel's positionX. If I made this into a command, where would I get the information for sender and e?

Comment: you can try EventToCommand from MVVMLight or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Comment: There's also an `InvokeCommandAction` coming from Expression Blend SDK, e.g. look [here](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/01/18/invokecommandaction-with-eventargs-as-command-parameter/). But for your example, I would recommend you to define an `InputBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `Commands` are used for Button-like controls, that trigger, when the user interacts with them (clicking the button, tapping it, etc.).

A `Command`, depending on your application design and needs, has a `CanExecute` and an `Executed` handler or event.
Those allow you to set, if the `Command` can execute at all, and what should happen, when it executes.

However, you're referring to a `PreviewMouseDown` event.
You cannot prevent the system from firing this event. So the `CanExecute` of the new `Command` is more or less useless in this scenario.

To still achieve your goal, you could use the `EventToCommand` mechanic, that *Ganesh* already pointed out in the comments.
[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) and the example below should give you a hint, how it will work:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="PreviewMouseDownCommandTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
          <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCommandProvider.PreviewMouseDownCommand,
                                            Mode=OneWay,
                                            Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>

      <!-- Content -->

    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the replies. I am getting the hang of commanding using MVVM Light with regular commands so far. I have another situation where I am trying to create a command using the PreviewMouseMove event. I think my issue at the moment is that I don't know how to send the value of the event args to the view model using commanding.

    var currentPosX = e.GetPosition(sender as GridSplitter).Parent as UIElement).X;